# New pull request to forked repo showing old outgoing commits which were already merged through old pull request

Tags: git, github

I am new to git. I am facing a situation: A week ago, I forked master branch of some other user's repo on GitHub, added my project to that and my changes were merged successfully through a pull request.

I did not delete that forked branch from my github.

I checked out this forked repo on a different machine and added another project to that.
I raised a pull request to merge my changes.

But this new pull request shows commits of my first pull request as well.
Have I messed up something? Please help.

Comment: Did you create a new branch off master or did you reuse the same branch? Or did you create a new branch based off the old branch?

Comment: I checked out the same one week old forked branch, but on a new machine.

Answer (score 0):

On your new machine, make sure you add the original repo URL (the one which has merged your first PR)

```
git remote add upstream /url/origin/repo
git fetch upstream
```

Then create your second PR branch from the updated upstream master branch

```
git checkout -b second_PR upstream/master
```

Comment: Let me try it out after reaching home and will update you.

Comment: I did as you said. It did not help. I ended up deleting that fork from my GitHub and forked again to start afresh. When I try to raise a new pull request to merge my new commits, it still shows old commits which are already merged. I just want to merge the new to-be-merged commits. Any idea why is it happening?

Comment: I think I should give a heed to this: https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/GitHub-pull-requests-showing-invalid-diff-for-already-merged/td-p/3000

Comment: @user2918640 the new fork should allow you to strart from the updated master branch: as long as your Pr branch starts from that updated master branch, your new PR should only reflect new commits.

Comment: Uninterestingly enough, it shows old commits. I'll keep trying and will update  soon.